# ostream on child object takes ostream of his parent

Tags: c++, polymorphism, ostream

I have a Game board full of Figurines.

Allocated:

```
board = new Figure*[boardSize];
for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) board[i] = new Figure[boardSize];

for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; ++j)
    {
        FreeSpot F( i,j );
        board[i][j] = F;
    }
}
```

I have two Classes

Figure:

```
class Figure {
  public:
        Figure          ( );
        ~Figure         ( void );

        virtual void  print ( ostream & os ) const;
        friend ostream  & operator << ( ostream & os, const Figure & F );

        int positionX;
        int positionY;
  private:
};

void Figure::print ( ostream & os ) const {
   os << "[" << positionY << "," << positionX << "]";
 }

ostream  & operator << ( ostream & os, const Figure & f ) {
   f . print ( os );
   return ( os );
 }
```

and as a child, FreeSpot:

```
class FreeSpot: public Figure {
  public:

        FreeSpot            ( int, int );
        ~FreeSpot           ( void );

        virtual void print ( ostream & os ) const;
        friend ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const FreeSpot & F );

        char shape;
  private:
};

void FreeSpot::print ( ostream & os ) const {
   os << "[" << positionY << shape << positionX << "]";
 }

 ostream  & operator << ( ostream & os, const FreeSpot & f ) {
   f . print ( os );
   return ( os );
 }
```

Problem is, that if I try to cout FreeSpot objects from board, it takes ostream of Figure.

```
cout << board[i][j];
```

Am I doing anything wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That because of [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

`board` is a container of `Figure`.  So when you do this:

```
    FreeSpot F( i,j );
    board[i][j] = F;
```

you squeeze a FreeSpot into a Figure.  The Figure subobject of F will be copied into the board, but the FreeSpot specific attributes will be lost.  So that the result will be a `Figure`.

This is why despite your call to a polymorphic `print()` you'll end up printing only Figures.

## Solution

You have to make board[][] an array of pointer to the elements. Or better: `shared_ptr`.  You won't anymore suffer from slicing. And memory maangement will be easier:

```
const int boardSize=8; 
vector< vector< shared_ptr<Figure> > > board(boardSize, vector<shared_ptr<Figure>>(boardSize));

for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; ++j) {
        board[i][j] = static_pointer_cast<Figure>(make_shared<FreeSpot>(i,j));
        cout << *board[i][j]<< " ";
    }
    cout<<endl; 
}
```